# copy() in data.table, R

Tags: r, data.table

I am attempting to assign a column by reference after I subsetted a `data.table` and assigned the return value to another `data.table` like so (toy example):

```
> x <- data.table(a=1:10, b=11:20, c=21:30)
> x
     a  b  c
 1:  1 11 21
 2:  2 12 22
 3:  3 13 23
 4:  4 14 24
 5:  5 15 25
 6:  6 16 26
 7:  7 17 27
 8:  8 18 28
 9:  9 19 29
10: 10 20 30
> y <- x[a==1 | a == 2, list(a,b,c)]
> y[,d:=a+b]
Error in `[.data.table`(y, , `:=`(d, a + b)) : 
  It appears that at some earlier point, names of this data.table have been reassigned.     Please ensure to use setnames() rather than names<- or colnames<-. Otherwise, please report     to datatable-help.
```

I don't exactly understand the issue: is it that the returned `y` is simply a "view" into the same memory as `x` and thus one should `copy` `x` before setting a column by reference?

Thanks

Comment: Can you construct a reproducible example and add it to your question?

Comment: Along with a reproducible example, please update to the latest version of data.table (1.8.2) so that we can all get on the same page to help out.

Comment: just updated the question with an example. this is data.table version 1.8.1. i cannot upgrade at this point unfortunately but imagine this happens in v 1.8.2 as well. if not, i will be happy with that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unable to reproduce the error with data.table 1.8.2 in R 2.15.1:

```
> x <- data.table(a=1:10, b=11:20, c=21:30); x
     a  b  c
 1:  1 11 21
 2:  2 12 22
 3:  3 13 23
 4:  4 14 24
 5:  5 15 25
 6:  6 16 26
 7:  7 17 27
 8:  8 18 28
 9:  9 19 29
10: 10 20 30
> 
>  y <- x[x$a==1 | x$a == 2, list(a,b,c)]
> 
> y
   a  b  c
1: 1 11 21
2: 2 12 22

> y[,d:=a+b]
   a  b  c  d
1: 1 11 21 12
2: 2 12 22 14
```